# Targeting dynamic id's within a javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In a php file I have tags with dynamic id's.

Example:

```
<ul id="<?php echo 'ul_'.$xx; ?>">
 <li id="test_li">...</li>
</ul>
```

In a separate JavaScript file I am wanting to use the load function and target that div.

```
$('<?php echo 'ul_'.$xx; ?>').load('../includes/myphpfile.inc.php #test_li');
```

My question is, how could I load that php within a JavaScript file?

Notes:- The reason I have it set up this way is due to looping multiple ul's. I just want my ajax file to refresh the li's within the specific ul I am inside of.

Edit: If I use classes instead of Id's it adds my newly inserted rows into all of the ul's with the same class. If I use a plain Id it only works on the first ul. Further explaining why I need to target the way I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to find a solution using the path I was on, I looked for alternate methods. Worked out I could add the event in the php file on the submit form button click.

The reason I wasn't using this method at first was because the code was running before it submitted to the DB and therefore was always behind in relation to the new data being submitted.

To my surprise I fixed this by just duplicating the line of code.

```
  <script>
  $("<?php echo '#enter_submit_button'.$linkid ?>").click(function(){
    /*1*/
    $('#<?php echo 'ul__'.$linkid; ?>').load('../includes/pursuit.inc.php <?php echo '#li__'.$linkid; ?>');
    $("<?php echo '#insert_new'.$linkid; ?>").fadeOut();
    /*2 with delay*/
    $('#<?php echo 'ul__'.$linkid; ?>').delay( 800 ).load('../includes/pursuit.inc.php <?php echo '#li__'.$linkid; ?>');
  });
 </script>
```

I honestly couldn't say exactly why this works but the logic behind trying the method came from hoping that the double load would pick up the latest submission.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be to put your JavaScript code into the PHP file inside
`<script></script>` tags, i.e, just before closing your `<body>` tag, do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('<?php echo 'ul_'.$xx; ?>').load('../includes/myphpfile.inc.php #test_li');
</script>
```

But if you *must* use an external js file, then you could do this:

Create a (.php) file and write:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
?>
// your js code with php inside (as you would do in HTML)
var othervar='<?php echo $phpVar; ?>';
//<?php //some php ;?>
```

Then, in your main (html/php) file, put in:

```
<script src='myjs.php' type='application/javascript'></script>
```

Hope that solves it.

Comment: If I wanted it to work that way wouldn't I have to re-load that page from my ajax file every time I submitted my form?

Comment: I didn't really go in to why you were doing it, as to how php could be embedded in js. So sorry!